# Switching User , SSH'ing into remote machine and executing command on one line. ('unknown': unknown terminal type.)

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, remotecommand, switch-user

This command use to work on RHEL5.8, however since we upgraded to 6.5 (bash version 4.1.2) it started outputting the following: 'unknown': unknown terminal type.

```
sudo su - *user* -c "ssh *remoteserver* 'sudo /etc/init.d/server1.sh status'"
'unknown': unknown terminal type.
'unknown': unknown terminal type.
SERVER Status: 'unknown': unknown terminal type.
                                     Running
```

Expected output is

```
SERVER Status:           Running
```

**Note:** When I use ssh -t it works, but im trying to avoid terminal clearing and extra output:  Connection to *remoteserver* closed.

Comment: The user's `.bashrc` isn't checking whether it's being run with a terminal, so it's trying to execute commands that need a terminal.

Comment: That's why it works with `ssh -t`.

Comment: If you're not sure which commands in the `.bashrc` are doing this, put `set -x` at the top of the script. It will show each command as it's executed, then you can see where the errors happen. And in case it's not obvious, I'm talking about the script on the remote server.

Comment: Thanks, however the script on the remote server is not the problem. It executes fine. I believe the problem resides in the with the ssh section of the command. Is there another way to acomplish this without ssh -t? Like I said, I want to avoid the disconnection output from a -t.

Comment: I'm not talking about the `server1.sh` script, I'm talking about the shell startup scripts. Those messages are NOT coming from `ssh` itself.

Comment: Ah sorry, I see what you're saying. The set -x was very helpful.

++ su - user -c 'env | grep ^VER_HOME='
++ awk -F= '{print $2}'
'unknown': unknown terminal type.